# Meteorjs - select DOM of a template from another template

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I have the following

```
<div id="header">
    {{> header}}
</div>

<div class="hidden content_box">
    {{> content}}
</div>
```

"content_box" is hidden at the start.

template "header" has a single button.

```
<template name="header">
    <button id="display_content">Click to display content</button>
</template>
```

template "content" is just a simple div

```
<template name="content">
    It's me, content
</template>
```

When I click on the button in the header, I want to "show" the content_box.

How do I achieve this? - or better yet, what is the best way to achieve this type of effect where you need to access the DOM of a template from an event of another template?

```
Template.header.events "click button#display_content": (e) ->
  Template.content.show() ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to do it, but in similar situations what I've done before is to use a session parameter to store the show/hide status of the div. In your click event, you then only need to change the value of the session flag. In the template of the div you want to show/hide, you just return the class name.

**Example in JS:**

```
Template.header.events({
    "click button#display_content": function () {
        Session.set('contentShow', true);
    }
});

Template.content.className = function (input) {
    return Session.equals('contentShow', true) ? '' : 'hidden';
};
```

Html

```
<template name="content">
    <div class="{{className}} content_box">
        It's me, content
    </div>
</template>
```

You'd need to initialise the session flag to false in `Meteor.startup()` for example `Session.set('contentShow', false);`. As session is reactive, the div class name will be re-evaluated automatically when you change the session flag.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! That would work of course. But it's very very different approach to the traditional way of front-end coding (by tradition, I guess I mean the popular way of doing via jQuery and HTML). Love to hear what others have to say and see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: True, and quite complicated for your use case, in this example you could probably simply do `$('.display_content').removeClass('hidden')` in your click event. Templates are just placeholders, they are not inserted in the dom so there is no way to do what you suggested. You will  have to do it the Meteor way for complex use cases e.g. the state is not changed simply by an onclick event, or standard jQuery/css selectors.